# Page numbering at the top centre

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm trying to place page numbering at the top centre (as required by submission guidelines at my university).

It should be a very easy thing to do, but it seems impossible... I spent a day familiarising with `fancyhdr` package but it adds up way too many useless things on the header (title of the chapter, section, etc.)... whilst I just need the page numbering.

Can somebody illuminate me on this issue?

---

this below is the updated MWE (as suggested by cmhughes). At the moment page numbering is all centred in the header, except for TOC, LOF, LOT and the first page of each chapter. Here, page numbering does not appear at all. Thanks a lot for you help guys! much appreciated

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.6}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{includeheadfoot,
  headheight=14pt,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields

\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{}

\author{}

\date{}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}

\begin{abstract}

lipsum

\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

lipsum

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\listoffigures 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}

\listoftables 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{}

lipsum

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's usually best to provide a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  where possible :)

Answer (score 15):

The following should do the trick

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

but in the absence of a complete MWE, it's hard to tell :)

The command `\fancyhf{}` clears all current headers and footers, and the `\fancyhead[C]{<stuff>}` command puts a header in the center.

If you want it to apply to the pages with the `lof`, `lot`, and `toc` as well, then you can redefine the `plain` pagestyle as detailed in the documentation of the `fancyhdr` package

```
% redefine the plain pagestyle
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % except the center
}
```

For reference, the following is a complete MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% redefine the plain pagestyle
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % except the center
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow it works! Thanks very much! The only problem is that it does not work for the list of tables, list of figures and the first page of each chapter... ...I'm trying to copy and paste the MWE in a sec

Comment: @AndreaLagna you're welcome :) it wasn't obvious from your question that you were concerned with the `toc`, `lof`, and `lot`; the `pagestyle` is different- I'll update my answer. Please remember a MWE for the future! Don't forget to upvote appropriate answers as soon as you have enough reputation to do so :) Welcome!

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
   
\chapter{}

\end{document}

Comment: ooch sorry that MWE looks quite messy... I will for sure as soon as I manage to familiarise with latex a bit ; ) thanks again

Comment: You can update the question and put the code there. That way, it's clearer to future readers as well. Also, make sure you mark the correct answer using the little "tick mark" below the vote symbols for the answer.