# Page number of ToC should be in the header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

The page number is in the footer not in the header, I used the answer of @cmhughes in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88574/page-numbering-at-the-top-centre) and it was good but as it is well known that the ToC may last for 4 or 5 pages not only one, that is, the first page numbering is still in the footer while the other pages were corrected. I need to make the page number of the first page of the ToC to be in the right side of the header. I used this code in the class:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% Table of Contents started here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\begin{spacing}{1}{

\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\@starttoc{toc}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
\cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
%%%%%%%%%%% Table of Contents ended here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and in the main file of my thesis I used this code:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\tableofcontents  % Write out the Table of Contents
\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: How can I thank you @Werner :) , thank you very much, it is working very good, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `\chapter`s set their first pages in the `plain` page style using `\thispagestyle{plain}`. A crude yet feasible solution would be to include

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Plain page style = Fancy page style
```

as part of your redefinition of `\tableofcontents`. This overwrites the `plain` page style (stored in `\ps@plain`) with that of `fancy` (stored in `\ps@fancy`). Placing it inside a group will localize the change.